# OpenVino: how to add support to FusedBatchNormV3 in model optimizer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, openvino

I am trying to understand how to add support for the TensorFlow layer FusedBatchNormV3 at the model optimizer of OpenVino. I am running on an Ubuntu 18.03 and using Tensorflow 15.

My goal is to do several tests with some pre-trained standard network on the Neural Computer Stick 2, and I am working with ResNet50 by now. I have downloaded the network as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
keras = tf.keras

input_shape = (200,200,3)
model = keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(input_shape=input_shape,
                                              include_top=False, 
                                              weights='imagenet')
```

After I have frozen `model` as described in [this post](https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-convert-trained-keras-model-to-tensorflow-and-make-prediction/).

I am running the model optimizer with the command:

```
sudo python3 mo.py \
--input_model ~<PATH_TO_MODEL>/model.pb \
--output_dir ~<PATH_TO_MODEL> \
--data_type FP16 -b 1
```

But I am getting this error message:

```
[ ERROR ]  1 elements of 64 were clipped to infinity while converting a blob for node [['conv1_bn_1/cond/FusedBatchNormV3_1/ReadVariableOp_1/Output_0/Data__const']] to <class 'numpy.float16'>. 
 For more information please refer to Model Optimizer FAQ (https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_Model_Optimizer_FAQ.html), question #76. 
[ ERROR ]  List of operations that cannot be converted to Inference Engine IR:
[ ERROR ]      FusedBatchNormV3 (53)
[ ERROR ]          conv1_bn_1/cond/FusedBatchNormV3_1
[ ERROR ]          conv2_block1_0_bn_1/cond/FusedBatchNormV3_1
[ ERROR ]          conv2_block1_1_bn_2/cond/FusedBatchNormV3_1
...
[ ERROR ]          conv5_block3_3_bn_1/cond/FusedBatchNormV3_1
[ ERROR ]  Part of the nodes was not converted to IR. Stopped.
```

I have found [this forum post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584797/openvino-model-optimizer-errorfusedbatchnormv3) suggesting to downgrade TensorFlow to version 13, but after doing so I also have got in another error with the same layer:

```
[ ERROR ]  Cannot infer shapes or values for node "conv1_bn_1/cond/FusedBatchNormV3_1".
[ ERROR ]  Op type not registered 'FusedBatchNormV3' in binary running on <USER>. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
```

My current idea is to add support for the FusedBatchNormV3 by using the Sub-Graph replacement introduced in the model optimizer (described in [this official page](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_customize_model_optimizer_Subgraph_Replacement_Model_Optimizer.html)). I would like to replace the function `FusedBatchNormV3` by the `ScaleShift` operation, since [here](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_Supported_Frameworks_Layers.html#tensorflow_supported_operations_and_the_mapping_to_intermediate_representation_layers) `FusedBatchNorm` is said to be associated to it, but I do not know how to find this `ScaleShift` object. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I cannot help with the replacement mechanism but I have another thing which should help.

According to the comment from https://github.com/opencv/dldt/issues/352 you can pretend that FusedBatchNormV3 behaves the same way like FusedBatchNorm and it does not lead to accuracy drop.

I added a patch to model optimizer which implements the behavior described above. Please check it out:
https://github.com/ArtemSkrebkov/dldt/tree/askrebko/treat_bnv3_as_bn

I checked inference results on the IR generated (using one picture) and I got the same top-3 as the Keras model gives.

Model optimizer command I used (Not sure about preprocessing parameters):
`python3 ./mo_tf.py --input_model ~/workspace/reps/keras_to_tensorflow/resnet-50.pb --input_shape [1,224,224,3] --mean_values [103.939,116.779,123.68]`

Is that solution OK to you?